# Modelling database for a small soccer league

Tags: sql, database-design, postgresql

The database is quite simple. Below there is a part of a schema relevant to this question

- ROUND (`round_id, round_number`)
- TEAM (`team_id, team_name`)
- MATCH (`match_id, match_date, round_id`)
- OUTCOME (`team_id, match_id, score`)

I have a problem with query to retrieve data for all matches played. The simple query below gives of course two rows for every match played.

```
select * 
from round r 
inner join match m on m.round_id = r.round_id 
inner join outcome o on o.match_id = m.match_id 
inner join team t on t.team_id = o.team_id
```

How should I write a query to have the match data in one row?

Or maybe should I redesign the database - drop the `OUTCOME` table and modify the `MATCH` table to look like this:

- MATCH (`match_id, match_date, team_away, team_home, score_away, score_home`)?

Comment: This'll be pretty messy as is... It'd probably be easiest to keep the outcome in the `MATCH` table, unless you have a reason to keep them separate. At the very least, a home/away flag or something similar in the `OUTCOME` table would simplify things greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost generate the suggested change from the original tables using a self join on `outcome` table:

```
select o1.team_id team_id_1,
       o2.team_id team_id_2,
       o1.score score_1,
       o2.score score_2,
       o1.match_id match_id
from outcome o1
inner join outcome o2 on o1.match_id = o2.match_id and o1.team_id < o2.team_id
```

Of course, the information for home and away are not possible to generate, so your suggested alternative approach might be better after all. Also, take note of the condition `o1.team_id < o2.team_id`, which gets rid of the redundant symmetric match data (actually it gets rid of the same `outcome` row being joined with itself as well, which can be seen as the more important aspect).

In any case, using this select as part of your join, you can generate one row per match.

Comment: I was considering self join but it seems that modifying match table would be a better solution. Sometimes it's really hard to choose:)

Comment: @drv Indeed. I am leaning towards the match table with match result solution myself. This approach doesn't keep the information about which teams are supposed to play against each other before the outcomes are available.

Comment: @drv, you could also consider having the teams in the match table and the outcome score in a separate table (i.e. adding `team_away` and `team_home` to `MATCH` and having `OUTCOME` be (`match_id, score_away, score_home`). Unless you need situations where there are not two teams for a match, at any rate... This could cause queries for all games a team has played in, though, so a home/away flag might be better if you want to have those types of queries as well...

Answer (score 0):

you fetch 2 rows for every matches played but team_id and team_name are differents :
- one for team home
- one for team away

so your query is good

Answer (score 0):

Using the match table as you describe captures the logic of a game simply and naturally and additionally shows home and away teams which your initial model does not. 
You might want to add the round id as a foreign key to round table and perhaps a flag to indicate a match abandoned situation.

Answer (score 0):

drop outcome. it shouldn't be a separate table, because you have exactly one outcome per match.

you may consider how to handle matches that are cancelled - perhaps scores are null?

Comment: Well, I also need to know which matches haven't been played yet. So in this situation the scores are null.

Comment: thought that might be the case. perhaps a special value of `-1` each? or for a "walkover" (one team didn't show), only that team gets `-1`. there are a few edge cases you'll have to handle.